# Appending a tag with interpolation using JavaScript in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a testing routine that creates a div tag, appends it to the body, and then sets its innerHTML property to:

> `<p>{{testVar}}</p>`

All with Javascript, like so:

```
var created = document.createElement('h1');

var elem = document.body.appendChild(created);
elem.innerHTML='<p>{{testVar}}</p>';
```

It then shows up on the page, double curly brackets and all.  What is the correct way to dynamically add this single element to my page so that the interpolation is recognized?

Comment: That's a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Simply don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile the HTML against the current scope, you can use a directive:

```
app.directive("myDynamicHtml", ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var compiledHtml = $compile("<h1><p>{{testVar}}</p></h1>")(scope);
            document.body.appendChild(compiledHtml);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: It should be `compiledHtml[0]`.

Comment: If I inject $compile into my Service service, can I $compile it there but against the $rootScope?

Comment: Yep, inject it where needed.